# Исключить из CIBlockElement::GetList товары с нулевой ценой

Tags: битрикс

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исключить из CIBlockElement::GetList товары с нулевой ценой? Есть запрос:

```
$res = CIBlockElement::GetList($array_sort, $arFilter, false, $navparams, $arSelect);
```

В нём я постранично вывожу по 8 товаров. Если делать костылём, то получится, что на одной странице выведется 6 товаров, на другой 5, на третьей ещё сколько то. Я понимаю, что надо в фильтре указать, чтобы он не пропускал товары, у которых цена равна null. Мой фильтр:

```
$arFilter = array("ACTIVE" => "Y", ["!CATALOG_PRICE_8"] => "null");
```

Из [документации](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/classes/ciblockelement/getlist.php) я подчеркнул, что есть различные проверки фильтра. И какой бы вариант я не попробовал:

```
["!CATALOG_PRICE_8"] => "null"
["!CATALOG_PRICE_8"] => null
["!CATALOG_PRICE_8"] = null
["!"."CATALOG_PRICE_8"] = null
["!"."CATALOG_PRICE_8"] => null
"CATALOG_PRICE_8" != null
"CATALOG_PRICE_8" > 0
```

либо выкидывает ошибку, либо не работает и всё равно пропускает

```
"arResult": [
    {
        "CATALOG_PRICE_8": null,
    }
],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему. Правильно было вот так:

```
$arFilter = array("ACTIVE" => "Y", "!=CATALOG_PRICE_8" => false);
```

Так же такая формулировка тоже работает

```
$arFilter = array("ACTIVE" => "Y", ">CATALOG_PRICE_8" => 0);
```